# how to get into command prompt when F8 does not work

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

is there any way to get a into Dos, without a xp disk or if F8 is not working.
have repaired a few blue screens of death with xp disk using repair or fixboot, fixmbr or chkdsk. tried to fix a pc over the phone but friend had no xp disk and just got blue screen.
would like to know if there is away around this.
kind regards

tony

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: windows xp service pack 3

Answer (score 2):

See ["Recovery console for those without an XP disk"](http://tips.vlaurie.com/2006/05/23/recovery-console-for-those-without-an-xp-disk/). Might help.

Answer (score 0):

From windows vista, you don't need use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open Command prompt in Recovery installation media, you can click Repair your computer > Then you might need to login as a local user and you can choose Command Prompt.